# jQuery multiple selectors, when some elements may or may not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In an attempt to avoid re-writing the same code over and over I tried using multiple selectors.

Generally, if one of these elements exist then the other ones do not.

```
    $('form#post, form#edit, form#quickpostform').submit( function()
    {
        // STUFF

        return false;
    });
```

*Should* this work?

Or does the fact that some of these may not exist break it?

Comment: I think it should work in all described by you cases.

Comment: Okay then I've broken something somewhere else then:P At least, that is progress! Thanks

Comment: I think you need a space between selectors for it to trigger though. Ex: $('form #post', form #edit, form #quickpostform')

Comment: @BIOS: no spaces has always worked for me before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will work, and  won't break,  the selector skips the id, if it won't be able to find that particular Id in the document..

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">test</div>
<div id="test1">test1</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#test,#test1,#test2').click(function(){
 alert('clicked');
});
```

see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/CPkaK/)

Comment: Indeed it does. I guess my "noobness" shines through here. I didn't think of testing it separately, I've just been hacking away at my code and refreshing.

Comment: :).. okies.. happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

It will work. You're selecting any elements that match any one of those selectors; each one may match 0 or more elements.

You can always test it for yourself.